# Get a sorted file list on a directory by using Linux bash script language

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, date

I need to list the files on a specified directory, and sort all available files on the basis of the date and time embedded in each file name, not by the file creation or modification date/time. My files have the following format:
Before sort

```
RATMS-RNSCA_npp_d20131208_t0408392_e0417432_b00001_c20131223024038606000_all-_dev.h5
RATMS-RNSCA_npp_d20131208_t0547506_e0557586_b00001_c20131223021256522000_all-_dev.h5
RCRIS-RNSCA_npp_d20131208_t0408392_e0417432_b00001_c20131223024038506000_all-_dev.h5
RCRIS-RNSCA_npp_d20131208_t0548226_e0557586_b00001_c20131223021256270000_all-_dev.h5
RNSCA-ROLPS_npp_d20131208_t0408334_e0417550_b00001_c20131223024038619000_all-_dev.h5
RNSCA-ROLPS_npp_d20131208_t0548233_e0558223_b00001_c20131223021256591000_all-_dev.h5
RNSCA-RONPS_npp_d20131208_t0408543_e0417005_b00001_c20131223024038636000_all-_dev.h5
RNSCA-RONPS_npp_d20131208_t0548391_e0558002_b00001_c20131223021256616000_all-_dev.h5
RNSCA-ROTCS_npp_d20131208_t0408168_e0417380_b00001_c20131223024038627000_all-_dev.h5
RNSCA-ROTCS_npp_d20131208_t0548017_e0558002_b00001_c20131223021256603000_all-_dev.h5
RNSCA-RVIRS_npp_d20131208_t0407405_e0417380_b00001_c20131223024038167000_all-_dev.h5
RNSCA-RVIRS_npp_d20131208_t0547150_e0558377_b00001_c20131223021256099000_all-_dev.h5
```

After sort (my expected results)

```
RATMS-RNSCA_npp_d20131208_t0408392_e0417432_b00001_c20131223024038606000_all-_dev.h5
RCRIS-RNSCA_npp_d20131208_t0408392_e0417432_b00001_c20131223024038506000_all-_dev.h5
RNSCA-ROLPS_npp_d20131208_t0408334_e0417550_b00001_c20131223024038619000_all-_dev.h5
RNSCA-RONPS_npp_d20131208_t0408543_e0417005_b00001_c20131223024038636000_all-_dev.h5
RNSCA-ROTCS_npp_d20131208_t0408168_e0417380_b00001_c20131223024038627000_all-_dev.h5
RNSCA-RVIRS_npp_d20131208_t0407405_e0417380_b00001_c20131223024038167000_all-_dev.h5

RATMS-RNSCA_npp_d20131208_t0547506_e0557586_b00001_c20131223021256522000_all-_dev.h5
RCRIS-RNSCA_npp_d20131208_t0548226_e0557586_b00001_c20131223021256270000_all-_dev.h5
RNSCA-ROLPS_npp_d20131208_t0548233_e0558223_b00001_c20131223021256591000_all-_dev.h5
RNSCA-RONPS_npp_d20131208_t0548391_e0558002_b00001_c20131223021256616000_all-_dev.h5
RNSCA-ROTCS_npp_d20131208_t0548017_e0558002_b00001_c20131223021256603000_all-_dev.h5
RNSCA-RVIRS_npp_d20131208_t0547150_e0558377_b00001_c20131223021256099000_all-_dev.h5
```

Please pay attention the 3rd (dYYYYMMdd) and 4th (thhmmssS) fields in each aforesaid file name. Prefix letter 'd' means date, and the prefix 't' means time.

NOTE: ‘YYYYMMDD’ represents the date of the start of the swath (YYYY: 4 digit year; MM: month; DD: day of month). The first and the second ‘hhmmssS’ represent the start and end of swath, respectively (hh -hour; mm: minutes; ss: seconds; S: 10th of a second).

I think my needs can be met to have the file list to be sorted by using "YYYYMMdd_thh" combination. How could I do that by using the Linux bash script language?

Thank you.

GoldenLee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will love bash. Just using the `sort` command, you can pass a "field delimiter" and select fields on which to sort.

From the man-pages:

> -t, --field-separator=SEP
>   use SEP instead of non-blank to blank transition
>
> -k, --key=KEYDEF
>   sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type
>
> KEYDEF  is F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]] for start and stop position, where
>   F is a field number and C a character position in the field;  both  are
>   origin 1, and the stop position defaults to the line's end.  If neither
>   -t nor -b is in effect, characters in a  field  are  counted  from  the
>   beginning of the preceding whitespace.  OPTS is one or more single-let‐
>   ter ordering options  [bdfgiMhnRrV],  which  override  global  ordering
>   options  for  that key.  If no key is given, use the entire line as the
>   key.

The needed parameters would become:

```
sort -t '_' -k 3,4 you_data_file
```

So we've divided your data into fields on underscores, and sorted on first the 3th field (the date) and then the fourth (the time). Because you were so kind to have a format for date and time with increasing precision, just alphabetic sorting works out.

Comment: Dear Noctua: I've just test your method. It's OK for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Technically, `sort` is not part of `bash` and you can use it with other shells (like [zsh](http://zsh.org/) or [fish](http://fishshell.com/) ...)

Comment: And it is a useless use of `cat`, just use `sort -t '_'  -k 3,4 your_data_file`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Ugh, stupid to place the cat. I replaced my `xclip -o` with `cat` without thinking. I'll modify it.